# Dynamic dest for ES6 Grunt configuration

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, babeljs

I'm trying to configurate Grunt to start using ES6, so that it transpire each component's JS file to it's own folder.

I have the next directory structure:

```html
Components
└──footer
│   └──js
│       └──footer.jsx
└──header
│   └──js
│       └──header.jsx
└──slider
    └──js
        └──slider.jsx
```

and I need to have the next result:

```html
Components
└──footer
│   └──js
│   │   └──footer.jsx
│   └──compiled
│       └──footer.js
└──header
│   └──js
│   │   └──header.jsx
│   └──compiled
│       └──header.js
└──slider
    └──js
    │   └──slider.jsx
    └──compiled
        └──slider.js
```

Currently I have the following configuration:

```
babel: {
        options: {
            sourceMap: true,
            presets: ['env']
        },
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: "src/Components",
                src: ["**/*.jsx"],
                dest: 'compiled',
                ext: '.js',
                extDot: 'first'
            }]
        }
    }
```

and it puts all compiled files into one common folder.

**How it should be configured to have compiled JS for each own component directory?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When [building the files object dynamically](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically) you can utilize grunts [rename](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#the-rename-property) property to generate and return a new destination path. The `rename` function is where you can handle the logic for this this type of requirement.

**Gruntfile.js**

```js
// ...
babel: {
  options: {
    sourceMap: true,
    presets: ['env']
  },
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: 'src/Components',
      src: ["**/*.jsx"],
      dest: 'src/Components', // <--- This should be the same value as `cwd`
      rename: function (dest, src) {
        var destParts = dest.split('/'),
          srcParts = src.split('/');

        srcParts.splice((srcParts.length - 2), 1, 'compiled');
        return destParts.concat(srcParts).join('/');
      },
      ext: '.js',
      extDot: 'first'
    }]
  }
}
// ...
```

**Notes**

1. The `rename` function accepts two arguments, namely `src` and `dest`.
2. Within that function both the `dest` and `src` path Strings are [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) into Arrays of items. Each item of each resultant Array is part of the path because `split('/')` uses `/` as the separator.
3. We then utilize [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to replace the second from last item in the Array, (which is the `js` part of the `src` path), with the new directory name, i.e. `compiled`.
4. Finally we [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)'enate all items of the new `srcParts` Array with the parts of the `dest` Array. This Array is turned back to a String joining items with `/` to form the new destination path. This new path String is returned.
5. The value of the `dest` property must match that of the `cwd` property in the `files` Object.

Comment: You're really helpful. Thanks for your answer!